# How can I get independent y-axes for two different series in a Highcharts chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I appreciate any and all help as I am very new to JS. I am trying to make a chart with 2 lines that have independent y-axes ranges so that one line doesn't look so flat. The data is from a CSV. The graphs are here: http://achouman-com.stackstaging.com/tester2-highcharts.html

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Stock Data - Highcharts</title>
        <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="/Highstock-6.1.0/code/js/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="/Highstock-6.1.0/code/js/modules/stock.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>

        <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on DOM loaded -->
        <script>
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


          Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                data: {
                    csvURL: 'http://achouman-com.stackstaging.com/example.csv'
                },
                rangeSelector: {
                    selected: 1
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Stock Price'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    max: 800,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Price (Dollars)'
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- 3. Add the container -->
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>                
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSV looks like this. It's example data. The real data is millions of rows, so I can't hardcode the data in the code.

```
 Index (xaxis),Dollars,Algorithm out
    1,3,300
    2,4.3,257
    3,2.1,357
    4,4.8,368
    5,3.4,469
    6,2.3,464
    7,3.2,358
    8,2.5,357
    9,2.4,678
    10,2.8,457
    11,3.7,468
    12,3.6,236
    13,3.5,347
```

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/ and https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.yAxis

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I’m getting the data through a csvURL. How do I access the CSV columns independently?

Comment: This link: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/custom-preprocessing#1 has some documentation on how to work with CSV files. There are many ways of course, but that link gives a general overview.